# JavaScript - Is node.parentElement considered DOM access?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I am trying to understand best practices around accessing and working with DOM objects. I have a script where I get the sibling cells of a table td by calling td.parentElement.cells each time the cell is clicked. Is this considered best practice or do I need to create and initialize an array of the cells of each table row, and search for the corresponding cells of a td that way?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on who you ask. Some will say don't traverse the DOM at all and keep the state/content in JS. Others don't mind. Either way this is an opinion

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Generally traversing a DOM is an old-fashioned and painful way to program. It works for doing a single modification, but the more your program modifies the DOM, the harder it is for *you* to mentally model what is, or could be, going on.

It is for that reason that front-end frameworks exist.

You can jump a few tens of centimetres into the air. If you practice very hard, even metres.

But that is not really making a contribution to building an aeroplane to fly long distances: the appearance of progress is illusory.

Have a look here to see how easy it can be when you don't have to traverse a DOM. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Declarative-Rendering

#### Trade-off

In answer to your question, yes they do add overhead. If minimising to the kilobyte level is crucial for you, then yes you should access the DOM directly, as this will take the smallest amount of code, so it is good practice when working under that constraint.

However, there are few circumstances when reducing code by 20-50k is crucial. Ask yourself, given how your web page will possibly develop over the years, how much time you are willing to spend updating code that traverses the DOM to make edits. Is that extra programmer time (which will not be noticed or appreciated by the end-user) worth it, given the alternative to learn something that extends your capabilities and do more?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do front-end frameworks not add overhead to an application's footprint? It's what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Thanks, Eureka. I think I got what I needed from your feedback. I shall definitely learn more about the front-end frameworks. For now, I am going with my current approach and optimize after I have a working solution.